# Java - immutable local variables

Tags: java, exception, coding-style, immutability

It is quite common "good practice" to make local variables `final` by default. Don't know about eclipse, but in IDEA there is even a checkbox in "create local variable" dialog. But there is one issue that doesn't let me use it every time. Take this code for example:

```
...
final Foo foo = null;
try{
    foo = getFromSomewhere();
} catch (IDontCareException e) {
    log.info(e, "looks like foo is not there);
}

if (foo != null) {
    doSomethingWithFoo(foo);
}

doSomethingElse();
...
```

The issue is that `IDontCareException` does not extend  `RuntimeException`... Is there any way to use `final` variable still?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: your IDE is telling you that you can't mark `IDontCareException e` as `final` because `IDontCareException` does not extend `RuntimeException`?

Comment: No, sorry for not explaining it right. I want foo to be final.

Comment: Don't understand the link between `final` keyword and an exception type ...

Comment: foo can't be final because you are setting it to null, and then trying to reassign it. You use the keyword `final` for when something is constant, which in your case it clearly isn't.

Comment: Well, then don't make it final. The code is still correct. I personally disagree with it being a good practice. It clutters the code with final keywords everywhere, and if methods are short as they should be, making the variables final doesn't add anything, IMHO, but reduces readability and increases verbosity.

Comment: *It is quite common "good practice" to make local variables final by default.* , only if you intend to make sure that you have by mistake not re-assigned the variable to something else while coding!!!

Comment: @JB Nizet why wouldn't you extract your comment to an answer?

Comment: @J-unior: because it doesn't really answer your question. You asked for a construct that lets you use the final keyword, and my comment doesn't tell you how. Only that I wouldn't care about using it (and why).

Comment: That's very fair of you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. write a helper method:

```
private Foo getFooOrNull() {
   try {
     return getFromSomewhere();
   } catch (Exception e) { return null;}
}
```

and then in your class:

```
private final Foo myFoo = getFooOrNull();
```

this will move the try/catch block out of the way and improve code readability, in addition to allowing yuo to keep you field final.

Comment: Leaving in the `null` is not helpful.

Comment: true, but you still need to know if you have a foo or not later on. the other alternative might be a mock Foo that does nothing, but thats a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
final Foo foo;
try{
    foo = getFromSomewhere();
} catch (IDontCareException e) {
    log.info(e, "looks like foo is not there);
    foo = null;
}

if (foo != null) {
    doSomethingWithFoo(foo);
}
```

EDIT: it doesn't compile. try this

```
Foo tmp;
try{
    tmp = getFromSomewhere();
} catch (IDontCareException e) {
    log.info(e, "looks like foo is not there);
    tmp = null;
}
final Foo foo = tmp;

if (foo != null) {
    doSomethingWithFoo(foo);
}
```

Comment: Indeed it doesn't compile ^^

Comment: well the compiler isn't as smart as I thought:)

Comment: ok this good, but when I see this code, I am really convinced that adding final is bad :)

Answer (score 2):

The definition of final is that you can't change what it references to. With `foo = getFromSomewhere()` you do exactly that. You can't do that. One option is to have it all in the try-block, as such:

```
try{
    final Foo foo = getFromSomewhere();
    doSomethingWithFoo(foo); //If getFromSomewhere() always returns a non-null value, otherwise you will still need the null-check
} catch (IDontCareException e) {
    log.info(e, "looks like foo is not there);
}

doSomethingElse();
...
```

Comment: that forces the field initialization and usage to be in the same place. if the field really is for one-time-use like this it can be made a local variable

Answer (score 1):

You could try for example:

```
private void myMethod(){
   try{
      final Foo foo = getFromSomewhere();
      if(foo != null){
         doSomethingWithFoo(foo);
      }
  } catch (IDontCareException e) {
   log.info(e, "looks like foo is not there);
  }
  doSomethingElse();
}
```

Comment: I assume `getFromSomewhere` is not going to return `null`. If it does, perhaps should be renamed to something like `maybeGetSomewhereOrNot`, or more likely rewrite it.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline That is a simple assumption, a lot of developers never care about this "naming" convention, although I agree with you. Thus, for this simple example, that is not focus on null-type checking, and without explicit `getFromSomewhere()`source code, checking for nullity isn't so stupid.

Answer (score 1):

A practice is good if it improves your code in a way or other. Adding final to all your variable without thinking is certainly not a good practice. 
By the way local variable are already scoped in a method and most of the time have a very short life. Why making them final ? Is it again a sort of micro optimisation ? Honestly you gain nothing with that. And you make your code less readable.

final indicates that your variable is constant, it is not the case here since you reassign your variable.
For me the good answer here is : don't make this variable final !